# HTML file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get file upload working for 3 different div ids (each with their own respective preview), I had come close to it working but the first div replaces the other two divs content.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the Javascript (not very well versed in js), any help would be extremely appreciated!

```js
function readURL(input, target) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var image_target = $(target);
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                image_target.attr('src', e.target.result).show();
            };
            
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
         }
    }  
    
    $("#pic1").live("change",function(){
        readURL(this, "#preview1");
    });
     $("#pic2").live("change",function(){
        readURL(this, "#preview2");
    });
     $("#pic3").live("change",function(){
        readURL(this, "#preview3");
    });
```

```css
.input-file-row-1:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.input-file-row-1{
    display: inline;
 margin-top: 25px;
 position: relative;
}

#preview_image {
  display: inline;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 2px 0px 0px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.upload-file-container { 
 position: relative; 
 width: 100px; 
 height: 137px; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 background: url(http://i.imgur.com/AeUEdJb.png) top center no-repeat;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 23px;
} 

.upload-file-container-text{
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #719d2b;
 line-height: 17px;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 position: absolute; 
 left: 0; 
 bottom: 0; 
 width: 100px; 
 height: 35px;
}

.upload-file-container-text > span{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #719d2b;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.one_opacity_0 {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 1px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="" method="post" action="#" class="feedback-form-1">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="input-file-row-1">
         <div class="upload-file-container">
                <img id="preview1" src="#" alt="" />
       <div class="upload-file-container-text">
                    <div class = 'one_opacity_0'>
                        <input type="file" id="pic1" label = "add" />
                    </div>
                    <span> Add Photo </span>
    </div>
   </div>
        </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
<form name="" method="post" action="#" class="feedback-form-1">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="input-file-row-1">
         <div class="upload-file-container">
                <img id="preview2" src="#" alt="" />
       <div class="upload-file-container-text">
                    <div class = 'one_opacity_0'>
                        <input type="file" id="pic2" label = "add" />
                    </div>
                    <span> Add Photo </span>
    </div>
   </div>
        </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
<form name="" method="post" action="#" class="feedback-form-1">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="input-file-row-1">
         <div class="upload-file-container">
                <img id="preview3" src="#" alt="" />
       <div class="upload-file-container-text">
                    <div class = 'one_opacity_0'>
                        <input type="file" id="pic3" label = "add" />
                    </div>
                    <span> Add Photo </span>
    </div>
   </div>
        </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: For my suggestion use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of  [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated

Comment: That solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "live" method is deprecated, instead change the code to:

```
$("#pic1").on("change",function(){
    readURL(this, "#preview1");
});
 $("#pic2").on("change",function(){
    readURL(this, "#preview2");
});
 $("#pic3").on("change",function(){
    readURL(this, "#preview3");
});
```